# Why doesn't the scrollbar-color property work directly on the body?

Tags: css, firefox

I'm trying to style my scrollbars properties, ie, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars. Anyway, when these properties are applied directly on the body, as in `body {...}`, they don't work. For example:

```css
body {
  scrollbar-color: rebeccapurple green;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 10000px"></div>
```

However, if you change it to a wildcard, then it works:

```css
* {
  scrollbar-color: rebeccapurple green;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 10000px"></div>
```

What exactly is going on here? Just in case, I'm using the latest Firefox on MacOS. Is this a bug?

Comment: Because it's not the `body` element that's scrolling; it's the `html` element.

Comment: @HereticMonkey You got it. Is this a Firefox specific thing? Seems like the body scrolls on Chrome.

Comment: Well, those scrollbar properties only work in Firefox according to the linked article, so maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it's the viewport that's scrolling, not `body`. And, since the value for the scrollbar properties on the root element (for HTML, the `html` element) are applied to the viewport:

```css
html {
  scrollbar-color: rebeccapurple green;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 10000px"></div>
```

Apply the CSS to the correct element and it works fine.

Credit goes to [Alohci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42585/alohci) for their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66738872/why-doesnt-the-scrollbar-color-property-work-directly-on-the-body/66738970?noredirect=1#comment117974791_66738970) with a careful reading of the [draft specification for the properties](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scrollbars-1).

Comment: It's actually the viewport that scrolling. The setting on the root element (i.e. in HTML the html element) is propagated to the viewport.

Comment: @Alohci Is this a Firefox specific thing? Because on Chrome, simply styling the `body::-webkit-scrollbar {...}` works.

Comment: [The spec for these properties](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scrollbars-1) says "UAs must apply the scrollbar-color/scrollbar-width value set on the root element to the viewport." and "Note: Unlike overflow (and overflow-\*) properties, scrollbar-color/scrollbar-width value set on the HTML body element are not propagated to the viewport." The -webkit-* experimental properties may not be compliant with that.